# Android using Scrollview in a scrollview

Tags: android

when i tried to use scrollview or webview in a scrollview, the inside scrollview or webview can not scroll. I can scroll with trackball but I can't scroll with touch. Do you have any idea about this issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found something and it works for me. I wanted to share. Here it is,
I have one scrollview and listview. listview inside scrollview. Scrollview-> RelativeLayout-> Listview. That listener belongs to Listview;

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        ScrollView().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: oops thanks a lot, for the last 3 hrs I have been trying to solve this issue. Almost I tried everything like customizing the scrollview, ontouch event, sv inside sv, list inside sv, onscroll(), onscrollchanged() but nothing worked for me. your soution worked. thank u so much.

Comment: You mean requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);  no?

Answer (score 0):

Android does not support using ScrollViews or ListViews inside each other. It's possible to do, but it's A Bad Thing (TM), according to Google developers.

Search SO for similar problems with ListViews, and you'll find several discussions + suggestions on how to hack around the limitations of the OS. However, I would strongly suggest you reconsider your layout to try and find some other way to handle your layout.

Answer (score 0):

ScrollView supports only one direct child; it can be either a LinearLayout or a RelativeLayout. If you have more than one children the scroll wouldn't work properly.

Comment: My layout architecture like this RealtiveLayout -> Scrollview -> Relativelayout->(childs) + relativeLayout -> scrollview -> RelativeLayout -> childs . So i guess that isn't the problem.